# Loop trough a list of referenced nodes, "entity_metadata_wrapper()" style

Tags: entities

I have a Template node that holds an Entity Reference multivalue field to a series of other nodes, all referenced nodes of the same type. The referenced nodes have a text field whose value I need to get.

In template node I have a computed field that do some calculations using the values from referenced nodes.

Now I have:

```
$tpl = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_plan_tpl');
$values = array();
foreach ($tpl as $field_item) {
  $values[] = node_load($field_item['target_id'])->field_some_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
}
```

How can I load the referenced entities in order to get field values, using `entity_metadata_wrapper()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`entity_metadata_wrapper()` has you covered, the entities will be lazy-loaded as you'd expect:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);

foreach ($wrapper->field_plan_tpl as $related_entity) {
  $foo_field_value = $related_entity->field_foo->value();
}
```